# ResponseObject to UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, afnetworking

I have made a POST-request with AFNetworking, and then i make a GET-request:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@",access_token] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    [manager GET:urlString parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Info: %@", responseObject);dataArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:responseObject, nil];

    self.tableViewObject.dataSource = self;
    self.tableViewObject.delegate = self;

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Here i get out a responseObject. I want to make it so that when u tap on the responseObject in the UITableView, i get into a new view with all the parameters within the responseObject. I can log the responseObject but I can't get it into my UITableView. My TableView looks like this:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [dataArray count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellId = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellId];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

And in .h:

```
@interface MyCardsVC : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
{
    NSArray *dataArray;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableViewObject;

@end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you hooked up your `UITableView` in the storyboard to your `IBOutlet` `tableViewObject`?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what you mean @JamesZaghini

Comment: I have right clicked and dragged the outlet as you can see in the .h-file if that is what you mean?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.  Your code looks fine to me.  The most obvious things would be that you haven't initialised the `dataArray`, so it's `nil`.  Or, you haven't hooked up the `tableViewObject` as per the previous comment.  Try setting some breakpoints and print out the values of `tableViewObject` and `dataArray`.

Comment: I can get out the dataArray but not the tableViewObject... @JamesZaghini

Comment: Is `self.tableViewObject` `nil` when you're debugging?  Then you probably haven't connected the `IBOutlet` to the `UITableView` in the storyboard.  My understanding is that you have nothing displaying in your table view.  Is that correct?

Comment: How can i see if its `nil`? And yes, that's correct!@JamesZaghini

Comment: When I run debug and hold the cursor over self, I can see `dataArray` and `_tableViewObject`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97800/discussion-between-james-zaghini-and-marck-kuhme).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set  datasource and delegate in ViewDidLoad

```
self.tableViewObject.dataSource = self;
self.tableViewObject.delegate = self;
```

Also, make sure when you have got the responseObject call [self.tableViewObject reloadData].

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@",access_token] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    [manager GET:urlString parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Info: %@", responseObject);dataArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:responseObject, nil];

    [self.tableViewObject reloadData];

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: All this code is inside ViewDidLoad! Just for testing. But when i try `[self.tableViewObject reloadData];`, it gives me an error.. @darshan

Comment: I got this: *Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe77bc80f70' *** First throw call stack:* and *terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException*.
@darshan